# rearrange data: add weeknumber from inside line above

Tags: r

I could need some help with rearranging data in R.

My data look like this:

```
"sometext for week 1"
"headertext", "1900", "1910", "1920"
"data1", 1,2,3
"data2", 2,2,2
"data3", 0,0,1
"sometext for week 2"
"headertext", "1900", "1910", "1930"
"data1", 0,0,3
"data2", 1,1,1
"data3", 1,0,0
```

And I use read.csv to import it inside R for now.

I need to arrange my data for plotting.
I can do it outside R pretty easy. The code in python would look like:

```
data = open("mydata.csv", 'r')
week = None
for line in data:
    if line[0:8]=="sometext":
        week = line.split(" ")[-1]
    else:
        print (week.stip() + "," + line)
```

and starting from there it also would be easy to format it in python like

```
"data1", 1900, 1, 1, 
"data1", 1900, 2, 0
"data1", 1910, 1, 2, 
"data1", 1910, 2, 0
"data1", 1920, 1, 3, 
"data1", 1920, 2, 3
...
```

But I guess it's better to skip any additional outside step and to do it inside R.

Any suggestions on how to do it in R?

Are there any functions or libraries I should use?

Comment: Your csv file is not valid if the number of columns is not the same in every row (e.g. some text for week 2 has only one column)

Comment: I know, but read.csv() will generate NA, and I don't need the lines with "sometext" for anything else than the weeknumbers. After updating the lines below sometext, the sometext line can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- read_lines('"sometext for week 1"
"headertext", "1900", "1910", "1920"
"data1", 1,2,3
"data2", 2,2,2
"data3", 0,0,1
"sometext for week 2"
"headertext", "1900", "1910", "1930"
"data1", 0,0,3
"data2", 1,1,1
"data3", 1,0,0') 

d1 <- d %>%
  split(cumsum(str_detect(., "week \\d"))) %>% # Use Regex to detect where subtables begin and split vector based on that. Results in list of the subtables
  set_names(map_chr(., ~ .x[[1]])) %>% # Set names of the list vector to the first line of the subtables
  map(~ read.csv(text = .x, skip = 1)) %>% # Parse each subtable with read.csv(), skipping the first line.
  bind_rows(.id = "week") %>% # Bind the subtables together into one. Names of the list of tables become the week variable
  as_tibble() # Convert to tibble, the tidyverse version of the data frame. Mostly for better readability of the console output
  
d1
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   week                      headertext X1900 X1910 X1920 X1930
#>   <chr>                     <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 "\"sometext for week 1\"" data1          1     2     3    NA
#> 2 "\"sometext for week 1\"" data2          2     2     2    NA
#> 3 "\"sometext for week 1\"" data3          0     0     1    NA
#> 4 "\"sometext for week 2\"" data1          0     0    NA     3
#> 5 "\"sometext for week 2\"" data2          1     1    NA     1
#> 6 "\"sometext for week 2\"" data3          1     0    NA     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. You even spotted the error in my example which I haven't noticed earlier (typo in year 1930, should be 1920 too, i guess its better to keep it that way, to not break your answer). Can you explain whats going on? I don't understand it.

Comment: I have edited the post and commented each line to explain what it does